# Powershell - Add one xml node at multiple positions

Tags: xml, powershell

I recently started learning powershell to change XML files. Now I’m having trouble adding new nodes at specific positions. 
I created one xml node 
`<Name2>Reference</Name2>` 
and want to insert it in every `<VFI>` node within one `<customer>` node.

XML File:

```
<WartbareEinheitenListe>
 <WartbareEinheit>
  <Name>John Wayne</Name>
  <Typ>STRUKTUR</Typ>
  <Customer>100008</Customer>
  <WartbareEinheiten>
   <WartbareEinheit>
    <Name>Wohnhaus</Name>
    <Typ>OBJECT</Typ>
    <Customer>100008</Customer>
    <VIF>                                     <---- Insert here
     <InfoFeld>
      <Name>Nummer</Name>
      <InfoFeldTyp>DECIMAL</InfoFeldTyp>
       <Inhalt>
        <Nummer>4500514</Nummer>
       </Inhalt>
     </InfoFeld>
    </VIF>
  </WartbareEinheit>
  <WartbareEinheit>
   <Name>John Wayne</Name>
   <Typ>OBJECT</Typ>
   <Customer>100008</Customer>
    <VIF>                                    <---- Insert here
     <InfoFeld>
      <Name>Nummer</Name>
      <InfoFeldTyp>DECIMAL</InfoFeldTyp>
      <Inhalt>
       <Nummer>5002449</Nummer>
      </Inhalt>
     </InfoFeld>
    </VIF>
   </WartbareEinheit>
  </WartbareEinheiten>
 </WartbareEinheit>
</WartbareEinheitenListe>
```

My Code:

```
$Path = "$env:....\Desktop\xmlpath.xml"

$xml = New-Object -TypeName XML
$xml.Load($Path)

$AlOb = $xml.WartbareEinheitenListe.WartbareEinheit.WartbareEinheiten.WartbareEinheit | Where-Object {$_.Customer -eq "100008"}

$AlOb2 = $AlOb.SelectSingleNode("VIF")
$R = $AlOb | Where-Object {$_.Typ -eq "OBJECT"}
$E = $R.Typ

for ( $i=0 ; $i -lt $E.count; $i++) {

$InfoFeld = $xml.CreateElement("InfoFeld")

$Mandant = $xml.CreateElement("Name2")
$MandantInhalt = $xml.CreateTextNode("Reference")
$Mandant.AppendChild($MandantInhalt)

$InfoFeld.AppendChild($Mandant)

$AlOb2.InsertAfter($InfoFeld,$AlOb.Node.VIF)
}
$NewPath = "$env:....Desktop\xmlpath2.xml"
$xml.Save($NewPath)
```

The result is that I get two new Elements for every VIF, which is correct, but my code inserts both Elements in the last VIF node.

Wheres my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

I guess I solved it myself:

I tried it with some array and now it works.

Code for Array:
`$Array = @($AlOb2)`

Code for InsertAfter:

```
$Array[$i].InsertAfter($InfoFeld,$AlOb.Node.VIF)
```

Wish u all a nice sunday

Q

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `SelectNodes()` method to select all `<VIF>` nodes:

```
$VIFNodes = $xml.SelectNodes('/WartbareEinheitenListe/WartbareEinheit/WartbareEinheiten/WartbareEinheit/VIF')
```

and then add your new `<Name2>` element to them with `AppendChild`:

```
foreach($VIFNode in $VIFNodes){
    $Name2Node = $xml.CreateElement("Name2")
    $Name2Node.InnerText = "Reference"
    $VIFNode.AppendChild($Name2Node) | Out-Null
}
$NewPath = "$env:....Desktop\xmlpath2.xml"
$xml.Save($NewPath)
```